# javascript form fields that need to repeat (loop) in the form

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Below is some HTML form code using a time picker. When I click on the first row, the time picker performs as expected. However when I try and add times to the second, or subsequent, rows it does not work. The `onClick` function displays the calendar, as it does in row one, however the values are not returned to the input cells.

The code below is generated within a loop command, with each row being assigned an indexed / unique values. Yet it still is not performing correctly. The HTML form  page itself is written in ColdFusion.

```
<cfoutput> 
   <cfloop index="z" from="1" to="3">

    <div class="table right">
      <input type="text" id="starttime#z#" placeholder="Time">
    </div>

    <div class="table right">  
      <input type="text" id="endtime#z#" class="icon" placeholder="Time">
      <a id="link#z#"></a>
    </div>

    <script>
    var endtime#z# = document.getElementById('endtime#z#');
    var timepicker = new TimePicker(['starttime#z#', 'link#z#'], {
      lang: 'en',
      theme: 'blue-grey'
    });
    timepicker.on('change', function (evt#z#) {
      var value = (evt#z#.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt#z#.minute || '00');

      if (evt#z#.element.id === 'link#z#') {
        endtime.value = value;
      } else {
        evt#z#.element.value = value;
      }
    });

    hljs.configure({ tabReplace: '  ' });
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>

</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say this code is being executed inside a loop.  Let's assume the loop makes the code run 3 times.  That means something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="endtime2" placeholder="Time">
```

Will appear on the page 3 times.  JavaScript will have trouble with this:

```
var endtime2 = document.getElementById('endtime2');
```

because there are 3 elements with id = endtime2.

You deal with this like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from = 1 to = 3 index = "idx">
<input type="text" id="endtime#idx#" placeholder="Time">
etc
var endtime#idx# = document.getElementById('endtime#idx#');
etc
```

Comment: YES thats how i have it the numeric values shown are dynamic per loop

Comment: So, what was the result?

Comment: example of the html source

Comment: (Edit) I do not know what that means. Did your new code fix the problem? If not, please [edit] your question to include any CF or JS error messages (check the browser's web console). Also, there are different time picker libraries, so please include a link to the specific one you are using.